# Obtener dato menor de una consulta SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo algunas horas tratando de resolver algo. Tengo una tabla con la siguiente estructura de prueba

```
create table temp_marco (
numcodigo INT NOT NULL,
numtalla INT NOT NULL,
prepacktallaint INT NOT NULL
)



INSERT INTO temp_marco VALUES (10001, 100, 2)
INSERT INTO temp_marco VALUES (10001, 120, 5)
INSERT INTO temp_marco VALUES (10001, 150, 1)
INSERT INTO temp_marco VALUES (10002, 150, 6)
INSERT INTO temp_marco VALUES (10002, 160, 5)
INSERT INTO temp_marco VALUES (10002, 180, 12)

SELECT * FROM temp_marco WHERE numtalla = (SELECT MIN(numtalla)FROM temp_marco)
```

Lo que intento hacer, es sacar el campo `prepacktallaint`, de cada registro donde el `numtalla` sea menor.

Por ejemplo con la tabla que cree de ejemplo, debería regresar los dos valores de `prepacktallaint` de su talla menor, es decir debería regresar los valores del **código 10001** en su **talla 100** y el **código 10002** cuando su **talla es 150**, ya que son las tallas menores de cada código.

Intenté con el select que agregué a la pregunta pero solo me regresa un registro.

Agregaré la consulta en fiddle para que sea mas claro mi problema

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a9096/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Además de las buenas opciones que te dio Javier, hay una muy cercana a tu código. El detalle es que tienes que usar una subconsulta correlacionada. Es decir, que dentro de la subconsulta vas a llamar columnas de tu consulta principal. Es importante resaltar que debido a esta funcionalidad, es una buena práctica siempre usar alias y prefijos en las columnas de la subconsulta.

Dejo el ejemplo del código

```
SELECT * 
FROM temp_marco o
WHERE numtalla = (SELECT MIN(i.numtalla)
                    FROM temp_marco i
                   WHERE i.numcodigo = o.numcodigo);
```

A pesar de no ser un indicador perfecto, este código tiene el plan de ejecución más simple de las 3 opciones presentadas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Existen muchas maneras de afrontar lo que comentas.

**Row_number**

Con esta función podemos obtener una serie de elementos numerados, y establecer una partición por cada numCodigo, de manera que:

```
With cte as (
    Select *, ROW_NUMBER()over (partition by numCodigo order by numTalla) rn
    from temp_marco

)
Select * from cte
```

[image: Res1]

Al particionar por numCodigo, solo necesitamos las filas cuya columna `rn=1`

```
With cte as (
    Select *, ROW_NUMBER()over (partition by numCodigo order by numTalla) rn
    from temp_marco

)
Select cte.numcodigo, 
       cte.numtalla, 
       cte.prepacktallaint
from cte 
where rn = 1;
```

[image: Res2]

La clave está en el partition by, y en el order by establecido dentro de Over. Variando estos, verás como el resultado se ve alterado.

**Apply**

Otra opción, es utilizar el operador apply, para que nos resuelva por cada fila del conjunto exterior, el mínimo del conjunto interior.

```
Select distinct temp_marco.numcodigo, 
                ca.numtalla,
                ca.prepacktallaint
                from temp_marco
Cross apply
(
    Select top(1) * 
    From temp_marco t
    where t.numcodigo = temp_marco.numcodigo
    order by numTalla 
) ca;
```

[image: Res3]

Aquí la clave está en la unión del conjunto exterior y el interior en el `Where t.NumCodigo = temp_marco.numCodigo`.

De manera que en el conjunto "principal", tenemos dos filas. Y la **"subconsulta correlativa"**, que nos da, el top(1) de lo que solicita para esa fila. Tener en cuenta siempre que top(1), va con un order by por la columna/s que queramos.

[Row_Number Numerar filas](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/11/row-number-numerar-filas/)

[Operador apply](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/06/27/operador-apply/)